# Make notifications bubble shorter

Tags: unity

These kind of notifications appear when I change volume, dropbox gets new files, etc. they stay there for about 10 seconds, This is what too long it should be around 2 seconds. How can I change this so that the desktop notifications go away faster?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a modified version of notify-osd that lets you configure a few parameters, like timeout, position, colors, etc...

I'll copy here the info I  saved some months ago for the installation:

Website with the information:

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/patched-notifyosd-with-close-on-click.html

PPA's:

https://launchpad.net/~leolik/+archive/leolik

https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8

Installation:

Install the patched NotifyOSD for Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leolik/leolik 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin
pkill notify-osd
```

1. Install NotifyOSDConfig (a GUI to configure the patched NotifyOSD):

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig

Now start NotifyOSDConfig and start tweaking the NotifyOSD notification bubbles.

The close-on-click feature is not enabled by default, so if you want to use this, enable it from NotifyOSDConfig!

NotifyOSDConfig doesn't come with settings for moving the notification bubbles, so you must do this manually, by using the command below:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.notify-osd gravity [number]
```

where is [number] can be:

1 - top-right corner
2 - middle-right
3 - bottom-right corner
4 - bottom-left corner
5 - middle-left
6 - top-left corner

Hope it helps. Only think I can say, it's working on 13.04, I haven't tried in 13.10. The repositories have packages for both versions so it shouldn't be a problem.

Good luck!

Comment: will this also work for lts, 12.04?

Comment: It should, since the ppa included packages for 12.04 last time I used that distro.